# Remove an object with conditions in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

For example, i have an array like that, in each object there are types of objects:

```
{
   {//ob1
   name = "zmg";
   link = "abccom";
   adress = "123 street";
   son = "2";
   },

   {//ob2
   name = "asf";
   link = "http://fsdfabccom";
   adress = "123 street";
   son = "1";
   },

   {//ob3
   name = "asf";
   adress = "123 street";
   son = "5";
   },

   {//ob4
   name = "sadfsdfasdf";
   link = "http://fsdfasdfasdfabc.com";
   adress = "123 street";
   son = "2";
   },

   {//ob5
   name = "asf";
   adress = "123 street";
   son = "4";
   },
}
```

What can I do if i want to delete all object, in which there is no object "link" (in this example: ob3, ob5 must be removed);
The result must be:

```
{
   {//ob1
   name = "zmg";
   link = "abccom";
   adress = "123 street";
   son = "2";
   },

   {//ob2
   name = "asf";
   link = "http://fsdfabccom";
   adress = "123 street";
   son = "1";
   },
   {//ob3
   name = "sadfsdfasdf";
   link = "http://fsdfasdfasdfabc.com";
   adress = "123 street";
   son = "2";
   },

}
```

Thank u so much!

Comment: You could use `NSPredicate` and `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way. you should read apple's documentation on this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(link != null)"];
NSArray *array2 = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Thank u, but i need just 1 questions to understand.
So that what can i do if i want to collect all the object with the link, which contain string"http://1df.com", for example ("http://1df.com/1faf", "http://1df.com/gfdfbcvb", "http://1df.com/ibic").
Thank you very much!

Comment: just change the predicate as below. I advice you to read the link I've put up in the answer as it will show you some clear examples on formats you can use with NSPredicates. 

`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(link beginswith '1df.com')"];`

Comment: Thank you. How about "or" (beginswith '1df.com' or beginswith '2df.com'). Sorry for annoying

Answer (score 2):

This should work. You filter the given array depending if there's a link or not.

```
    NSArray *newArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return evaluatedObject.link;
    }];
```

And it's even easier in Swift:

```
let filtered = array.filter { (item) -> Bool in
    return item > 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

filteredArrayUsingPredicate (as mentioned above) is a good idea to get you a list of the items to delete - then create a new array minus the items to delete.

Mind you, you could also perform the query in the opposite way so you are returned the array of items you want to keep. Then keep that around and use it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
NSArray* filteredArray = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN self.@allKeys" ,@"link"]];
```